# How to tell GCC to ignore warnings in some source files?

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, suppress-warnings

There are a few sources files in my project that are automatically generated by a tool. Unfortunately, these sources cause GCC to issues some warnings which is quite inconvenient. Is there a way to tell GCC to ignore warnings for these source files, without modifying the sources? They shouldn't be modified because, as I've said, they are auto-generated.

The warnings are mostly about incompatible pointer types and implicit function declaration.

Comment: There are quite a few options listed at the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) that will suppress certain warnings. So it'll also depend on the warnings.

Comment: It would be good to know what those warnings are; not all warnings have the same cause (and solution).

Comment: Did you try to fix it from the other end? i.e. Can the tool be corrected to emit code without warnings? Ignoring them is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: @BlueMoon That is not an option. It is a well established and pretty old tool and modifying it would only complicate the matter for myself and everyone else.

Comment: @Evert The warnings are mostly about incompatible pointer types and implicit function declaration.

Comment: Well, the documentation I linked you to has at least this: "You can request many specific warnings with options beginning with ‘-W’, for example -Wimplicit to request warnings on implicit declarations. Each of these specific warning options also has a negative form beginning ‘-Wno-’ to turn off warnings; for example, -Wno-implicit." Seems one way to suppress those implicit function declaration warnings.

Comment: And a very quick search also yields "-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types"; that seems to be the other.

Comment: @Evert My problem wasn't disabling the errors, but disabling them only for a few files. I was looking for something that didn't require writing special make rules. :)

Comment: Ok. Your question was (is) unclear: "Is there a way to tell GCC to ignore warnings for these source files". It's even weirder if you accept the below answer while you state "that didn't require writing special make rules".

Comment: @Evert I tried to avoid making separate rules, but wasn't strictly against it. But that is not possible (apparently), so I did create new rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible if you are building project through a makefile. You will just have to create different rules for those files. For example by creating another set of CFLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) gives the following example, apparently relevant to your case:

> You can request many specific warnings with options beginning with
>   `-W`, for example `-Wimplicit` to request warnings on implicit
>   declarations. Each of these specific warning options also has a
>   negative form beginning `-Wno-` to turn off warnings; for example,
>   -Wno-implicit.

You can also turn off warnings about incompatible pointer types, with:

```
-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types"
```